# 'texdoc' fails when some other texlive-* is installed by 'apt'

Tags: texlive, texdoc

I had installed TexLive from 'texlive2020-20200406.iso' correctly in Ubuntu 20.04, and I had used it to write reports for a while. Recently, I found some packages through terminal command `apt search texlive` and I installed some of them. From then on, the command `texdoc` can't search document anymore. I'm sure the command worked well previously.

Example: The command `texdoc beamer` opened 'beameruserguide.pdf' before, but now it opens a beamer sample in another path.

It seems the packages installed through `apt` override the path of those installed from 'iso` file.

`apt list --installed | grep texlive` gives list below:

```
texlive-base/focal,focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-binaries/focal,now 2019.20190605.51237-3build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
texlive-font-utils/focal,focal,now 2019.202000218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-fonts-extra-links/focal,focal,now 2019.202000218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-fonts-extra/focal,focal,now 2019.202000218-1 all [installed]
texlive-fonts-recommended/focal,focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-chinese/focal,focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed]
texlive-lang-cjk/focal,focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-japanese/focal,focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-korean/focal,focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-other/focal,focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-latex-base/focal,focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-latex-extra/focal,focal,now 2019.202000218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-latex-recommended/focal,focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-pictures/focal,focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-plain-generic/focal,focal,now 2019.202000218-1 all [installed,automatic]
```

I'm very thankful if you can help me solve this problem.

---

Addition: The path is set via editing '~/.bashrc' as below (after installation from '.iso')

```
export MANPATH=${MANPATH}:/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/man
export INFOPATH=${INFOPATH}:/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/info
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux
```

---

Addition: Command `which texdoc` and `echo $PATH` outputs:

```
# which texdoc
/usr/bin/texdoc
```

( *I wrap lines for easier reading* )

```
# echo $PATH
/home/xiaocy/.local/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:
/snap/bin:
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux
```

---

Conclusion

The problem is caused by the path override. Modify `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` as below can solve this problem.

```
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/man:${MANPATH}
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/info:${INFOPATH}
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}
```

*I don't know whether it's allowed to give this conclusion myself. The conclusion is drawn with the help of @daleif (see comments). Thank you very much!*

Comment: You now have two latex installations (the uso does not install via apt). How exactly did you add the path from 4ye uso installation to your system?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. I just add the path to '~/.bashrc' after installation from '.iso' file, and didn't modify it after `apt`. (Please see the updated) @daleif

Comment: Paths are searched from left to right, so you're just appending here, meaning the apt texlive is found first. Prepend! Additionally, also add this to your `.profile`, any editor started via a menu or double click never uses a bash shell so never see the change (you'll need to log out and in again for profile changes to take effect)

Comment: I added the paths in the front of `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`, logged out and in again. But it didn't work ( `texdoc beamer` for example). Can I uninstall the apt texlive ? And ... how to do that?

Comment: what does `which texdoc` say? and `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question. Thank you ! @daleif

Comment: You still have the path change at the end , you nedd to use `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}` that is what we mean by prepending. You are appending and thus programmes are found from the apt installation before the search gets you the TL2020 installation

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake! I re-edit the `.bashrc` and `.profile`,  and it works correctly now. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake. First of all, OSes search the PATH from left to right. (Here the path is separated by colons). It then appends each path piece to a function call until the first one is found. Here you have two latex installation the apt one and a TL2020 via ISO. Since the apt installation adds texlive stuff in such a way it is found via `/usr/bin/`, we beed to make the TL2020 part of the path comes before `/usr/bin/`. The standard method is to make sure to *prepend* the TL2020 path.

Therefore use

```
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/man:${MANPATH}
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/info:${INFOPATH}
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}
```

not

```
export MANPATH=${MANPATH}:/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/man
export INFOPATH=${INFOPATH}:/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/info
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux
```

Additionally, make sure to also add this to `.profile` (you'll need to log out and in again for a `.profile` edit to have any effect). This is because any editor started via a menu or by double slicking a file never sees anything Bash related and thus never sees the change.